# REST equivalent of CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates?

Tags: docusignapi

The SOAP method CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates takes a list of [TemplateReference](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/TemplateReference.htm) objects which allows me to create a 1-1 mapping of documents in my ECM system to DocuSign Templates. This has worked great up until now and has allowed me to build an envelope creation algorithm without having to know how many documents are involved in a specific use case.

SOAP however does not support the new Payment tabs. In trying to find a REST replacement for this API call I haven't been able to find a way to create an envelope where each document references a different Template. The [envelopes: create](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=Envelopes&operations=create) method for example only allows for one templateID in the envelopeDefinition. Is there a way to port the functionality I've built over to REST?

BONUS QUESTION: Why does the DocuSign backend differentiate between SOAP and REST created envelopes when applying Templates? I didn't expect to be able to programatically create Payment tabs on an envelope with SOAP, but I'm surprised specifying a Template with Payment tabs using SOAP prevents those tabs from working.

This is my SOAP call with non-functional referencing a Template with non-functional Payment tabs:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
            <TemplateReferences>
                <TemplateReference>
                    <TemplateLocation>Server</TemplateLocation>
                    <Template>8E556CD1-D343-4C07-9401-D88B00A67671</Template>
                    <Document>
                        <ID>90267</ID>
                        <Name>DS - Template Mapping - 12/4/2017 John Payme2 (90267)</Name>
                        <PDFBytes>omitted</PDFBytes>
                        <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
                    </Document>
                    <RoleAssignments>
                        <RoleAssignment>
                            <RoleName>Payer</RoleName>
                            <RecipientID>37974046</RecipientID>
                        </RoleAssignment>
                    </RoleAssignments>
                    <Sequence>1</Sequence>
                </TemplateReference>
            </TemplateReferences>
            <Recipients>
                <Recipient>
                    <ID>37974046</ID>
                    <UserName>John Payme2</UserName>
                    <Email>ANDREW.MORTON@HYLAND.COM</Email>
                    <Type>Signer</Type>
                    <AccessCode />
                    <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>
                    <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                    <Note/>
                    <RoleName>Payer</RoleName>
                </Recipient>
            </Recipients>
            <EnvelopeInformation>
                <AccountId>9cace92e-1384-4cf7-9b4c-a2bd70aab9a1</AccountId>
            </EnvelopeInformation>
            <ActivateEnvelope>true</ActivateEnvelope>
        </CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: In you request you are mixing lot of things which are not correct and you are using CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates operation which has lot of limitation per DocuSign documentation, so I have updated my response with the correct operation (CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms) with which it is working fine as per expectation. Please test and let me know if it works for you. On another note, if you are doing a new development then why you want to use SOAP API, instead of REST API?

Comment: Did you test with CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms opeartion as explained in my answer?

Comment: I did, and the Payment tabs appear to function like I would expect. However, 1) the envelope gets created with the PDF that I used to create the template instead of the PDFBytes I provide in the API call, and 2) when I try to build an envelope with two documents and apply one template to each I get separate signer notification emails for each template, even though the recipient name and email is the same. The CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates call would smartly recognize that this was one recipient even though the RecipientID was different from template to template.

Comment: You will be providing PDF bytes in an inline template or in documents, and you need to put sequence number of inline template with lower value, say 1 and sequence number of server template should have value 2. Then document in an envelope will come from Inline Template/document node instead of server template. When you are adding two documents, how you are adding it on an envelope? And I can see you have already accepted an answer which means all your issues are resolved, isnt it?

Comment: I accepted the answer when I thought the solution was to move to REST. I'm still having trouble with CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms - giving the inline template an earlier sequence than the server template gives an exception -  "the docid specified in the tab element does not refer to a doc in this envelope" - probably because I set the doc ID to be the unique ID of the document in my ECM system. This wasn't an issue with the old method, and I'm not sure I see a way around without downloading the Template's Tab list and changing the doc ID on each one.

Comment: When you give sequence number of inline template, you are saying to the system that document will come from Inline Template and replace the document present in the server template. So docId should have same value as present in the server template, if its different then you will get above error, it will be same with REST API as well. Your code in old method was also not correct, you were referring templateId, and passing pdfbytes as well, which is not correct, you should do one of those two options.

Comment: Then it sounds like a happy accident that the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates was doing what I wanted it to. Is there a recommended pattern then in either SOAP or REST to do what I'm attempting - take one or more documents and apply a server template to each one, while providing a new docID for each one so I can later match up the signed documents with the original in my repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **Composite Templates** in the REST API.  Composite templates are a very powerful feature though they can get complex pretty quickly - using CTs you can do things like combine a template and a document in the same envelope, or combine multiple templates, etc.

One of the better resources on composite templates is the features page on Templates found in the Developer Center, which has a section for composite templates:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates#composite

There's a section in the Envelopes:create API documentation that talks about [composite templates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create#composite-templates).

---

Example Usage:

Here's a quick sample from one of the above resources, in this example two templates are combined into one single envelope:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Composite Templates",
    "emailBlurb": "Composite Templates Sample 1",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "55A80182-2E9F-435D-9B16-FD1E1C0F9D74"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "johndoe@email.com",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Buyer"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "2",
            "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "2",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "sallydoe@email.com",
                    "name": "Sally Doe",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Seller"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! It looks like in your example since my documents are coming from outside of DocuSign I would just provide the PDF bytes to each inlineTemplates' document component and the inline template template should only apply to that document, correct?

Comment: It's been a while since I've tested but yes I'm pretty sure what you mention is correct, it should use those inline document bytes if supplied.

Answer (score 2):

Ergin responded to your primary qs, now for your Bonus qs, DocuSign will still allow you to create an envelope using SOAP API if you are using template which has Payment tabs. I don't see any issue in creating an envelope using SOAP API. I tested it, and I got the payment screen at the time of signing. Please find the SOAP Request to create an envelope with Payment's Template. It uses different operation CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms and CompositeTemplate design pattern. You just have to set accountGuid, TemplateGuid and RoleName which is set in a template.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
      <ActivateEnvelope>true</ActivateEnvelope>
      <EnvelopeInformation>
        <AccountId>{{accountId}}</AccountId>
        <Subject>Test SOAP Subject</Subject>
        <EmailBlurb>Test SOAP Body</EmailBlurb>
      </EnvelopeInformation>
      <CompositeTemplates>
        <CompositeTemplate>
          <ServerTemplates>
            <ServerTemplate>
              <Sequence>1</Sequence>
              <TemplateID>{{TemplateId}}</TemplateID>
            </ServerTemplate>
          </ServerTemplates>
          <InlineTemplates>
            <InlineTemplate>
              <Sequence>2</Sequence>
              <Envelope>
                <AccountId>{{accountId}}</AccountId>
                <Recipients>
                  <Recipient>
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <RoleName>Signer1</RoleName>
                    <UserName>Signer 1</UserName>
                    <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
                    <Type>Signer</Type>
                  </Recipient>
                </Recipients>
              </Envelope>
            </InlineTemplate>
          </InlineTemplates>
        </CompositeTemplate>
      </CompositeTemplates>
    </CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: That runs counter to my testing, and my DocuSign account rep informed us that Payments would not work with SOAP when we asked about it. I'd be curious to know what you're doing differently.

Comment: Payments would not work if you are populating Payments tab in the SOAP request, but if you are just referencing template which has Payments Tab and populating just signer details in the SOAP request then everything will work.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then. Trying it just now if I create an envelope through the Console the Payment screen pops up when I finish signing. Creating the envelope through CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates the payment fields just appear as plain text amounts on the document, and the Payment screen never appears. I'll update my question with the API request log.